# How do I handle IEEE-754 floating point numbers in JSON?

Tags: json, ieee-754

[The comments on Tim Bray's post about RFC-7159](https://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/201x/2014/03/05/RFC7159-JSON#c1394164399.202543) note that you can't use `NaN` or `Infinity` in JSON numbers:

> My one major pain point with JSON - and one I had sincerely hoped
>   would have been addressed - is that the numeric format is not IEEE 754
>   compliant. In fact, this text puts an explicit nail in that coffin:
>
> > "Numeric values that cannot be represented in the grammar below (such
> >     as Infinity and NaN) are not permitted."
>
> Which means we're often left with either putting all numeric data in
>   strings; or simply disregarding the standard and using "Inf" and "NaN"
>   in our JSON numeric fields. Neither is ideal of course, but such is
>   life.

Trying to JSON-encode a `NaN` (`JSON.stringify(0/0)`) or an `Infinity` (`JSON.stringify(1/0)`) on Chrome gives me `"null"`, and parsing `"null"` of course gives me `null`, which doesn't have the properties of `NaN` or `Infinity` when used with numbers:

```
> null*0
0
> NaN*0
NaN
```

Do I have any better options than the ones listed in the comment?

1. Pass numeric data as strings
2. Ignore the standard and use `Infinity` and `NaN` (which still raises the question: how do we get the JSON encoders and decoders to accept that?)